# Return first x items in a group of groups

Tags: c#, linq

I'm querying a datatable and I seem stuck on selecting a group of groups.

This code

```
var grouping = table.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => curveids.Contains(x.Field<short>("CurveID")) && x.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp").Hour >= hour && x.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp").Hour < (hour + 1))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp")).Where(x => x.Select(y => y["CurveID"]).Count() == curveids.Count);
```

Groups by timestamp and returns a group of x curves, where x = curveid.Count(). It contains 5000ish groups.

However for each day there can be more than one timestamp.

```
int nrdays = grouping.GroupBy(z => z.Key.Date).Count();
```

tells me there are 255 distinct days.

I would now like to group this again, but not by time stamp but by calendar day and then take the first (as in earliest) group for each day. I tried this:

```
var grouping2 = grouping.GroupBy(z => z.Key.Date).OrderBy(a => a.Key).Take(curveids.Count);
```

but this only returns 4 groups and I dont get why?
It should return 255 groups with each of them containing the same timestamp and x curveids, so x*255 record sets.

The datatable has 3 columns, Timestamp (DateTime), CurveID(short), Price(double).

**UPDATE**

As requested by Mr Skeet a full example:

```
    public class listprx
    {
        public DateTime timestamp;
        public int curveID;
        public double prx;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<listprx>();

        // populating data
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(i);
            var tempdt = new DateTime(2016, rand.Next(1, 12), rand.Next(1, 29), rand.Next(1, 23), rand.Next(1, 59), 0);

            if(i % 3 == 0)
            {
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 1, prx = rand.Next(1,50)});
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 2, prx = rand.Next(1, 50) });
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 1, prx = rand.Next(1, 50) });
            }
            else
            {
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 1, prx = rand.Next(1, 50) });
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 2, prx = rand.Next(1, 50) });
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 3, prx = rand.Next(1, 50) });
            }
        }

        // setting hour criteria
        int hour = 16;
        int nrcurves = 3;

        // grouping by timestamp and only take those where all curves are there, (as close to the desired time as possible
        var grouping = data.Where(x => x.timestamp.Hour >= hour && x.timestamp.Hour < (hour + 1))
            .GroupBy(x => x.timestamp).Where(x => x.Select(y => y.curveID).Count() == nrcurves);

        // Grouping by day and take only the time stamp that is closest to the hour
        // this fails
        var grouping2 = grouping.GroupBy(z => z.Key.Date).OrderBy(a => a.Key).Take(nrcurves);

        Console.WriteLine("Nr of timestamps with all curves {0}, nr of days {1}, nr of groups in second group {2}, expected same as nr days"
            , grouping.Count(), grouping.GroupBy(z => z.Key.Date).Count(), grouping2.Count());

        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have removed the random element and simplified further:

```
public class listprx
{
        public DateTime timestamp;
        public int curveID;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var data = new List<listprx>();

        // populating data
        var tempdt = new DateTime(2016, 4, 6, 16, 1, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (i == 2)
            {
                tempdt = tempdt.AddDays(1);
            }

            if(i % 2 == 0 )
            {
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 1});
            }
            else
            {
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 1});
                data.Add(new listprx { timestamp = tempdt, curveID = 2});
            }

            tempdt = tempdt.AddMinutes(i+1);
        }

        // setting hour criteria
        int hour = 16;
        int nrcurves = 2;

        //grouping by timestamp and only take those where all curves are there, (as close to the desired time as possible
        var grouping = data.Where(x => x.timestamp.Hour >= hour && x.timestamp.Hour < (hour + 1))
            .GroupBy(x => x.timestamp).Where(x => x.Select(y => y.curveID).Count() == nrcurves);

        //Grouping by day and take only the time stamp that is closest to the hour
        //this fails
        var grouping2 = grouping.GroupBy(z => z.Key.Date).OrderBy(a => a.Key).Take(nrcurves);

        Console.WriteLine("Nr of timestamps with all curves {0}, nr of days {1}, nr of groups in second group {2}, expected same as nr days"
            , grouping.Count(), grouping.GroupBy(z => z.Key.Date).Count(), grouping2.Count());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The expected end result is:

```
Timestamp        CurveID
------------------------
6/4/16 16:02        1
6/4/16 16:02        2
7/4/16 16:06        1
7/4/16 16:06        2
```

Comment: It would be easier to both understand the question and help you if you could provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. (I'd suggest using a list as the source data, with regular properties, rather than a `DataTable`...)

Comment: I will add sample data but the data comes from a database and I load it with sqladapter so it ends up in a datatable

Comment: Yes, it ends up in a `DataTable` in your real code - but you should demonstrate the problem in the simplest possible way. Unless you believe the `DataTable` is actually part of the problem, you shouldn't include it, as it's more complicated than just using a `List<T>`.

Comment: Got you. I will rewrite in simple list example but this will take a bit of time

Comment: @JonSkeet: please see updated for full example with list. Could you please let me know whether it is clear?

Comment: Well it's not as clear as it could be - you haven't shown expected results and actual results, and by introducing randomness, it's possible we won't get the same results as you. I don't see why you've added 50,000 results - why not just have a list of about 10 entries? Additionally, I can't see that you're using `prx` anywhere, so it's irrelevant. It really is important to reduce this to a *minimal* example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108538/discussion-between-nik-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: Hey @nik I edited my answer to work with your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer working on your example.

Ok, I went trought your example and fixed some bugs and my answer. Let's clear code a bit and comment what went wrong where.

Our models will be

```
public class Curve
{
    public int CurveID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class CurveGroup
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Curve> Curves { get; set; }
}
```

next is function to generate test data:

```
public static List<Curve> GetData()
{
    var data = new List<Curve>();
    var startTime = new DateTime(2016, 4, 6, 16, 1, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2)
        {
           //startTime.AddDays(1); - this line does nothing, DateTime is an immutable struct so all function changing its value returns a new copy
           startTime = startTime.AddDays(1);
        }

        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
           data.Add(CreateNewCurve(startTime, 1));
        }
        else
        {
           data.Add(CreateNewCurve(startTime, 1));
           data.Add(CreateNewCurve(startTime, 2));
        }

        //startTime.AddMinutes(i + 1); same issue as above
        startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(i + 1);
    }

    return data;
}

public static Curve CreateNewCurve(DateTime time, int curveID)
{
    return new Curve()
    {
        Timestamp = time,
        CurveID = curveID
    };
}
```

and here goes main function

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var data = GetData();

    int hour = 16;
    int totalCurveCount = 2;

    var grouping = data
           .Where(x => x.Timestamp.Hour >= hour && x.Timestamp.Hour < (hour + 1))
           .GroupBy(x => x.Timestamp)
           .Where(x => x.Count() == totalCurveCount); //there is no need to select curveId like in your code: Where(x => x.Select(y => y.curveID).Count() == nrcurves);

    var grouping2 = grouping
           .GroupBy(x => x.Key.Date)
           .Select(x =>
                new CurveGroup
                {
                   Timestamp = x.Key,
                   Curves = x.OrderBy(c => c.Key).Take(totalCurveCount).SelectMany(c => c)
                }
           );


    foreach (var g in grouping2)
    {
        foreach (var c in g.Curves)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.Timestamp);
            Console.WriteLine(c.CurveID);
        }
    }
}
```

this returns expected results.

Your code failed because your second grouping is not taking (`Take(nrcurves)`) values in groups but groups themselves. So instead of returning 255 groups with 2 values in each you return 2 groups with all values in them.

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: I cleared a bit my answer. I'm using anonymous objects but my suggestion would be to create simple models and work with them.